# Downloading Sentinel-1 SLC in individual bursts

Tags: api, download, sentinel-1, copernicus, insar

I'm about to embark on a DInSAR time series project, for which I will be using Sentinel-1 single look complex (SLC) data. 
Sentinel-1 SLC products are only available in Interferometric Wide-swath (IW) format, which consists of three subs-swaths, further subdivided in bursts (see figure 1 on page 3 of [this document](http://step.esa.int/docs/tutorials/S1TBX%20TOPSAR%20Interferometry%20with%20Sentinel-1%20Tutorial_v2.pdf)). The data volume for the complete time series I want to analyze would be around 8TB when downloaded with complete SLC images. Since I don't have the data storage capacity for these volumes and given that my research area is rather small, I would prefer to download individual bursts per SLC image.

Would it be possible to download individual bursts of an SLC image as opposed to the whole wideswath? If so, how can it be done with the Copernicus Scihub API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the Copernicus Scihub does not feature to download single bursts, nor does any of the other portals (ASF, PEPS, AWS...). This is because of the data structure of Sentinel-1 SLC products.

As a work-around, you can download the 8GB zip, perform *TOPS Split* to select the burst you need (and only VV polarisation), and delete the zip file afterwards. A single polarisation product consisting of one burst is extracted in about one minute (8 GB RAM on my machine) and requires around 120 MB of disk space. You can then proceed with *Apply Orbit File*, *BackGeocoding* and so on.

One note: Even if you are using a single burst, you have to apply *TOPS Deburst* after calculating the intereferogram. Only then you can create a spatial subset of the product.

Comment: I wonder if there are any developments on this topic.  Is it still the case that none of the other portals are not providing such a capability ?